# Name of printer media trays

Tags: java, printing

I currently retrieve some printer information about the possible media trays with this code snippet:

```
 Media med[] = (Media[])printService.getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, null, null);
 if( med != null ) {    
     for (int k=0; k<med.length; k++) {
          sb.append("Name : " + med[k].getClass() + " - Value : " + med[k].getValue() +
                " - Name : " + med[k].getName()+"\n" );
     }
 }
```

Sadly, this just returns some tray numbers, which I find relatively useless:

```
Name : class javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName - Value : 40 - Name : media
Name : class javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName - Value : 41 - Name : media
Name : class javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName - Value : 42 - Name : media
... more ...
Name : class sun.print.Win32MediaTray - Value : 5 - Name : media
Name : class sun.print.Win32MediaTray - Value : 25 - Name : media
Name : class sun.print.Win32MediaTray - Value : 26 - Name : media
Name : class sun.print.Win32MediaTray - Value : 27 - Name : media
```

How can I retrieve useful names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you all printer properties, including tray names

```
String printName = "HP Officejet Pro 8500 A910 (Network)";
AttributeSet aset = new HashAttributeSet();
aset.add(new PrinterName(printName, null));
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, aset);
for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
  PrintService service = services[i];
  System.out.println(service);
  DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
  Object o = service.getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, flavor, null);
  if (o != null && o.getClass().isArray()) {
    for (Media media : (Media[]) o) {
      System.out.println(media + " ID: " + media.getValue() + "\t" + media.getClass().getName());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `media.toString()` (which is what you do in the println) gives a "useful" name; one has to separate between the `MediaTray` class which are the actual trays, and `MediaSizeName` class which are media sizes. These can't be used as class parameter for `getSupportedAttributeValues()`, `Media.class` still needs to be used. What a pain.

Answer (score -1):

This code retrieve the Printer Name, media tray name by size and id:

```
public static void printByName(String printName) {
//Inicio Codigo PrintByName
    try{
        AttributeSet aset = new HashAttributeSet();
        aset.add(new PrinterName(printName, null));
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null,aset);
    MediaSizeName mn=null;
    MediaSize mz=null;
    Destination dd=null;
    for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
        PrintService service = services[i];
        System.out.println(service);
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
        Class category = Media.class;
        Object o = service.getSupportedAttributeValues(category, flavor,null);
        if (o == null) { // Attribute is not supported
            } 
        else if (o.getClass().isArray()) {
            // Attribute values are a set of values
            Media[] media = (Media[]) o;
            for (int j = 0; j < media.length; j++) {
                //System.out.println("ATributo: " + media[j].getValue() );
                if(media[j] instanceof MediaSizeName) {
                mn=(MediaSizeName)media[j].clone();
                //mz=getMediaSizeForName(mn);
                mz=MediaSize.getMediaSizeForName(mn);

                //System.out.println((media[j].toString()));
                System.out.println("\t Bandeja: \t\t"+ mn + " ID: " + mn.getValue() );
                }
                }
            }
        }
    //System.exit(0);
    } catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Exception is " + e);
            }    
}
```